# Failed to Save Files on Storage [FileSystemException] Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, file, permissions, storage

I uploaded an android photo compress application in play store and I checked every thing is ok, but some users have issue that the application can not save compressed photos, I checked that and I found this error

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/My Folder/photo.jpg' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

This is permissions `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

This line inside application tag

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I looked for some solutions and founded this permission line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

But when ask for this permission android shows to user warning the application will access to all files without asking permission, I feel this is worrying for users and some may be afraid of this permission, however I uploaded the application but it was rejected because using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: have you tried implementing this package? https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler it will handle everything.. follow the documentation

Comment: What was Android version of device giving that error? It would be normal for all Android 11+ devices.

Comment: Create your folder in public Documents directory and the error goes away.

Comment: @Danny I am using permission_handler to ask user for permissions but as I said the previous error shows.

Comment: @blackapps As far as I know, the error appeared in the following systems: Android 11 and 12

Comment: @blackapps What do you mean by public documents directory?

Comment: I said public Documents directory. Take a file manager app and you will find it on your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right regarding `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Your app will be removed from play store if you don't have valid reasons. You may have to create a video and explain why you need these permission, and how scoped storage can't help you.

Now, you should know one thing that you are trying to create a folder directly inside internal storage. This will work in lower android versions but will fail in Android 10 or above even when you have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted.

Try creating your files inside public directories like Download or Documents. If the files downloaded doesn't need to be accessed by users then you can always save in your package folder `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`

Hope this helped you! If you have any further doubts feel free to comment down below.